# Autoplay not working

Tags: dvd, windows-media-player, autoplay

The auto play on my DVD drives suddenly stopped working for some reason. Even with store-bought DVDs it does not work, although I can watch movies quite successfully if I run Windows Media Player and then manually select the drive.

I have tried setting the autoplay options through *Start » Set Default Programs* and setting Default programs. I cannot get autoplay to work.

My theory is that it is not recognizing when a new DVD is ready and that autoplay is never called. When I insert a new DVD, it's ready for a little while but then the access light goes out. When I use the computer, the DVD name shows up, but when I try to play the DVD I get told that there is no program associated with the DVD and that I should set as one to the *Start » Set Default Programs*, as mentioned above.

If I reset to the "ask me each time" and try reinserting the DVD, it never asks me what to do. It merely reads the desk for a little while and then stops – exactly as above.

Any ideas? (Oh!  Win7)

Comment: which Windows version?

Answer (score 0):

so I finally figured out what was wrong: apparently I was missing a registry value. What I  determined :

Open regedit and locate the following key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

Change:  NoDriveTypeAutorun to 0x91

If necessary create this key as a DWORD.

I found this in: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_autoplay.htm.

Change/add this value, and then reboot. Voilà! – Autoplay is back!

Ross

Comment: Actually, the reboot is not needed

Comment: Sir, if you found the solution please mark it as solve as it helps for other users too.